# Calculating TextView size

Tags: android, textview

I am creating elements programmatically in the `onCreate()` function of my activity. I am trying to calculate the height of a `TextView` that uses `wrap_content` for it's height, but cannot retrieve this value from this function.

Is there a better function in the activity's lifecycle to create these elements from or is there a way I can calculate the height needed for a TextView using a specific typeface, size, and linespace value and set it manually?

Comment: please add come codes to get the whole context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View's getWidth() and getHeight() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0)

Comment: check this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014530/get-what-the-wrap-content-height-would-be

Comment: you can use AutoReSizeTextView , that is custom implementation to mange size of text dynamically in TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lifecycle `onCreate()`, [those views are draw**ing**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3594216/9035237), so you are not able to get the view width / height at that time.

You can use `View.post()` to get the draw**ed** (real) width / height, like the second item in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035591/9035237 said.